# Is there a way, without Spark UDFs, to blend two distribution DataFrames that have different support?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What I have is two `DataFrame`s, each representing a probability distribution, but each stored one entry per row. For example one is `df1`:

```
item_id |  probability
--------|---------------
  item1 |      0.1
  item2 |      0.2
  item3 |      0.7
```

and another, let's call it `df2`:

```
item_id |  probability
--------|---------------
  item2 |      0.3
  item3 |      0.5
  item4 |      0.2
```

and please notice that the item space for these two are different. But this is ok because what it means is that `df1` has zero probability for `item4` and `df2` has zero probability for `item1`. What I'd like is code without heavy use of custom UDFs that basically produces a `DataFrame` that, given some `alpha` double value, blends those two distribution. I can write this with custom UDFs but I'm wondering if there's some pure Spark SQL based code that does this with only built-in functions.

```
item_id |  probability
--------|---------------
  item1 |      0.1 * alpha + 0.0 * (1 - alpha)
  item2 |      0.2 * alpha + 0.3 * (1 - alpha)
  item3 |      0.7 * alpha + 0.5 * (1 - alpha)
  item4 |      0.0 * alpha + 0.2 * (1 - alpha)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is totally doable with SQL.  The secret is an "outer" join with some coalesce magic to handle nulls.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._


val someData = Seq( ("item1", 0.1 ), ("item2", 0.2),("item3", 0.7) )  
val alpha = 1.1

val someMoreData = Seq( ("item2", 0.3 ), ("item3", 0.5),("item4", 0.2) )  

val df1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(someMoreData).toDF( "item_id","probability" )
val df2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(someData).toDF( "item_id","probability" )
val prob = df2
  .join(df1, df1("item_id") === df2("item_id"), "outer" )
  .select( 
    coalesce( df1("item_id"), df2("item_id") ).alias("item_id"), 
    coalesce( df1("probability"),lit(0.0)).alias("probability1"),
    coalesce( df2("probability"),lit(0.0)).alias("probability2"), 
    lit(alhpa).alias("alpha") )
prob.show()
+-------+------------+------------+-----+
|item_id|probability1|probability2|alpha|
+-------+------------+------------+-----+
|  item3|         0.5|         0.7|  1.1|
|  item2|         0.3|         0.2|  1.1|
|  item1|         0.0|         0.1|  1.1|
|  item4|         0.2|         0.0|  1.1|
+-------+------------+------------+-----+

prob.select( prob("probability1") * prob("alpha") +  prob("probability2").multiply( lit(1.0) - prob("alpha")), prob("item_id") ).show();
+---------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|((probability1 * alpha) + (probability2 * (1.0 - alpha)))|item_id|
+---------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|                                                     0.48|  item3|
|                                                     0.31|  item2|
|                                     -0.01000000000000...|  item1|
|                                      0.22000000000000003|  item4|
+---------------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks, I had something like this but somehow your select statement `coalesce( df1("item_id"), df2("item_id") ).alias("item_id")` helped to clear up my thinking on this. I accepted this because you got it in slightly before @mckraqs answer, which is also correct.

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved with a full-join and simple operation. Here you have a snippet. Just bear in mind, that for clarification I changed `prob` names in both dataframes to `prob1` and `prob2` respectively. Then it's just something like:

```
alpha = 0.5
df = df1 \
    .join(df2, how='full', on='item_id') \
    .fillna(0) \
    .withColumn('prob', alpha * F.col('prob1') + (1-alpha) * F.col('prob2'))
```

Your data sample:

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=[
    ('item1', 0.1),
    ('item2', 0.2),
    ('item3', 0.7)
], schema=['item_id', 'prob1'])

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=[
    ('item2', 0.3),
    ('item3', 0.5),
    ('item4', 0.2)
], schema=['item_id', 'prob2'])
```

Comment: Thank you! I accepted the answer from @Matt Andruff only because it was sooner.

Comment: Np, glad I could help!